# How to re-write methods to add together an instance variable and a local variable which produces a new variable of data type Double?

Tags: java, scope, refactoring

For my assignment I have been asked to create an two methods. These two methods are called "addx()" and "testParsing()". The purpose of these two methods are as follows

**addx() method**

- Calculate 12 + 5 using an instance variable names "x" and a local variable named "x". (the assignment is about scope)
- The method which does the addition should add the instance variable x by the parameter x.
- Returns a new Double().

**testParsing() method**

- tests that x("12 + 5") returns a Double with the value 17

I have at the moment done the addx() and the testParsing() methods differently to this although the outcome is the same. The way I have done it so far looks far looks like this:

```
public Double addx(double x)
    {
            System.out.println("== Adding ==");
            this.x = x;
            return new Double(x + 5);
    }
public void testParsing()
    {
if (addx(12.00) == 17.0) {
        System.out.println("Adding Success");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Adding Fail");
    }
    }
```

So as you can see, I have not added together an instance variable and a local variable. I have defined the instance variable as the local variable ad added 5 onto it which is not what was asked. I am looking for a way to re-write this so that the addx method adds() method adds both the instance variable which should be equal to 12 and the local variable which should be equal to 5 together to equal 17 and return a new value of type Double (I'm not sure why it is type object Double and not a primitive double but that's what has been instructed.

Here is my attempt of re-writing the methods correctly:

```
 public Double addx(double x) {
      System.out.println("== Adding ==");
      this.x = 12.00;
      x = 5.00;
      return new Double();//how do I make the value be stored in this Double()?
}

public void testParsing()
{
if (addx("12 + 5") == "17.0")//error string cannot be converted to double?
{
     System.out.println("Adding Success");}
else {
     System.out.println("Adding Fail");
}
}
```

I know that the attempt doesn't make sense, but I'm stuck on how to fix it.

So to clarify:

- I want to make addx() add the instance variable x to the parameter x.
- testParsing() should test if ("12 + 5") adds up to 17.

Thanks.

Comment: You can't have a local variable **and** a parameter named x. Are you sure you understood the assignment correctly?

Comment: @Quagaar, a parameter is a local variable

Comment: @AndrewTobilko: Yes, sure, your're quite right about that.

Comment: Are you able to share what the method `x("12 + 5")` does since it appears to be missing? Or is the method called `x()` supposed to be `addx()`? I assume that method `x()` is supposed to parse the String parameter. But it is important to know what it does. Judging by what `addx()` is supposed to do, I'd guess that `x()` must pass the first value 12 to the constructor and 5 to the `addx()` method?

Comment: Yes x() is suppose to be addx() which should parse the String parameter.But I am having trouble with figuring out how to parse x("12 + 5") to addx.

Answer (score 0):

**`addx()`**

```
public Double addx(double x)
{
        System.out.println("== Multiplying ==");
        this.x = x;
        return new Double(x + 5);
}
```

Few things here:

1. Your `sysout` statement indicates that you think that you are multiplying numbers. You are not - you are adding two numbers and returning the results.
2. `this.x = x;` - I'm not sure what you are trying to accomplish. You are essentially overwriting the value of the instance variable 'x' with the value of the local variable 'x'.
3. Why are you returning a double where you are adding 5 to x?

Without giving you the answer, here are a few things to explain. Within the method `addx()`, `x` refers to the local variable. Therefore, if you call the method with `addx(10);`, `x` is equal to 10. To refer to the instance variable, you must use `this.x`. So, if your instance variable is equal to 1, and you call `addx(10);`, you expect that the return value will be `11.0`. How can you achieve that result, knowing that within the body of the method, `x` is `10`, and `this.x` is `1`?

**`testParsing()`**

The intent of this method is to create a *unit test* for the `addx()` method. It wants you to test that code. Therefore, one of your variables must be `12`, and the other must be `5`. You can do the following:

- Assign `5` to your instance variable `x`;
- Call `addx()` with the parameter `12`;
- Assign the return value of `addx()` to a `Double`;
- Verify that the double is equal to `17.0`.

The verification could be done using assertions, or throwing an AssertionError, for example. Has the instructor provided more details as to how to make that verification?